# Add LDAP user as new member of a security group in Non Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: powershell, ldap

Can someone help me create a Powershell script that can add an existing user as a new member of a directory security group? I don't have Microsoft Active Directory server, I am using Zentyal Server and which my understanding is that it's using a Samba3 directory service.

I am able to create a new user account to this LDAP server using the following Powershell script but I cannot figure out how to add the user as a new member of a security group named Production.

This is the powershell script used to add new user to the LDAP server.

```
# Server credential
$ldapServer = "LDAP://w.x.y.z/DC=acne,DC=local"
$ldapUsername = "username@snap.local"
$ldapPassword = "user_password"

# Connect to the LDAP server

$conn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries($ldapServer, $ldapUsername,         
$ldapPassword)
$conn.AuthenticationType = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::Secure

$properties = @{
    "sAMAccountName" = "user"
    "userPrincipalName" = "user@acne.local"
    "userAccountControl" = 66048
    "givenName" = "User"
    "sn" = "One"
    "displayName" = "User One"
}

# Add new user to the LDAP

$cn = "CN=" + $Props\["displayName"\] + ",CN=Users"
$newUser = $Conn.Children.Add($cn, "user")

foreach ($p in $Props.GetEnumerator()) {
    $newUser.Properties\[$p.Key\].Value = $p.Value
}

$newUser.CommitChanges()
$newUser.Close()
```

I tried using property/attribute "memberOf" with value "cn=production, cn=users, dn=acme, dn=com"

Comment: What happened when you tried to set `memberOf`?

Answer (score 0):

Once the user is created :

```
$groupDn = "Your Group distinguished name"
$group = [ADSI]"LDAP://$groupDN"
$group.Member.Add("Your User distinguished name") | Out-Null
$group.SetInfo()
```

You can do the same to remove a user by simply replacing the `Add` method with the `Remove` one.

Note that will not work for integrated security principals. For those, only groups within the Builtin containers are available and the DN must be replaced by the SID with a string that match this one `<SID=S-.*>`